# ANN model for indefinite number of inputs and outputs

Tags: neural-networks, modeling

Say we have

- a large set of possible input attributes (N)
- a large set of possible output attributes (M)

Where N,M > 10000

A smallish (yet indefinite) subset of input attributes is assigned to every object. Based on this set we're supposed to generate a small subset of output attributes.

**Example**

Inputs:

- I_A
- I_B
- ...
- I_Z

Outputs:

- O_A
- O_B
- ...
- O_Z

Example expected results:

```
 I_A, I_C, I_Z        --> O_G, O_H
 I_B, I_X             --> O_A, O_C, O_G, O_Z
 I_A, I_D, I_J, I_K   --> O_A
```

The number of inputs is not related to the number of outputs, although the number of inputs and outputs assigned to an object is usually small (< 10).

The obvious solution is to create an ANN which takes a binary vector of all possible input attributes and returns a binary vector of all possible output attributes. However given that the number of attributes assigned to an object is very small comparing to the number of all possible attributes this solution doesn't look very optimal.

Am I exaggerating here, or is there a trick to reduce the number of inputs and outputs of the ANN?